# Material UI Autocomplete margin sizing issue

Tags: css, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield, margin

I have the following issue. I'm using Material-UI Autocomplete in my project. I made some alterations so the font and the component resize when the viewport changes size. Thus I've used vw on widths,heights and font-sizes. However, as you can see in the gif bellow, when I resize the gap between the green sauce and the blue/red spaces increases. how can I make sure that the gap also follows the initial proportion? So basically what I would like is that the whole component shrunk and the gap didn't increase. I've been altering all kinds of heights/margins but I can't seem to solve the issue. You have all the code available on the following sand box.

https://2y3jh.csb.app

[image]

Comment: If you change the height of `.makeStyles-root-4` to `3vw` it doesn't have a gap: https://imgur.com/iYSIOu6

Comment: Can you please detail how can I alter that height? Feel free to alter my sandbox code and point to the correct spot where I should make the change!

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the input height to `3vw` so that the height is consistent.

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "3vw", // Changed from 2vw
    fontSize: "1.25vw",
    color: "#02112E",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  },
  option: {
    fontSize: "0.8vw",
    height: "3vw",
    width: "100%",
    color: "#02112E"
  },
  noOption: {
    fontSize: "0.8vw",
    height: "3vw",
    width: "100%",
    color: "#02112E"
  },
  root: {
    "& label + .MuiInput-formControl": {
      marginTop: "1vw"
    },
    "& label.Mui-focused": {
      color: "#02112E",
      fontSize: "0.97vw"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "#02112E",
      borderBottomWidth: "0.21vw",
      left: "0",
      transformOrigin: "left center",
      transition: "all 0.3s ease"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:before": {
      borderBottomColor: "#02112E",
      borderBottomWidth: "0.07vw"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:hover::before": {
      borderBottomColor: "#02112E",
      borderBottomWidth: "0.07vw"
    },
    fontSize: "1.25vw",
    width: "100%",
    height: "3vw",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: "#02112E",
    fontSize: "1.25vw",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    transform: "translate(0, 2vw) scale(1)"
  }
});

export default function StyledAutoComplete() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      style={{ width: "60%" }}
      options={list}
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        option: classes.option,
        noOptions: classes.noOption,
        input: classes.input
      }}
      disableClearable
      freeSolo
      noOptionsText={"No Options"}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(option) => <React.Fragment>{option.title}</React.Fragment>}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          {...params}
          label="Option"
          variant="standard"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: "new-password" // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.inputRoot
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const list = [{ title: "opt 1" }, { title: "opt 2" }];
```

**Demo:** https://2zh36.csb.app/

**Output:**

[image]